# Monty Hall Problem With Uneven Door Probabilities

Tags: probability, statistics, mathematical-modeling, monty-hall

In the conventional Monty Hall problem it is assumed that the probability of the car being placed behind any of the three doors is the same (namely, $\frac{1}{3}$). (In other words, the host has no inherent bias of placing the car behind a door versus the other two). But what if the probabilities of the car being behind doors 1, 2, or 3, with probabilities $p_1, p_2$ and $p_3$ respectively, are such that the assumption $p_1 = p_2 = p_3$ is not necessarily true.

To test whether switching would be beneficial, I decided to experiment using python. I tested switching every time, not switching any time, and randomly deciding whether to switch one million times each. For each option, I used python to generate three random (technically pseudo-random) probabilities, then carried out the experiment. (I will spare you the details of the programming).

The results for each option I got were very close to $0.5$. This means that it does not matter whether we switch, do not switch or randomly decide to switch. But more surprising is that given three doors with uneven probabilities of having the car behind, the probability of winning the car is $0.5$ (assuming the contestant picks randomly). Is there any mathematical justification to this? Is my interpretation of the results correct?

Edit-- Here is the code snippet for generating random probabilities that I used:

```
def prob_gen(): #Generates random probabilities
    prob_a = round(random.uniform(0, 1), 4)
    prob_b = round(random.uniform(0, 1 - prob_a), 4)
    prob_c = round(1 - (prob_a + prob_b), 4)
    return [prob_a, prob_b, prob_c]
```

Full code is here: https://www.pastiebin.com/5a4d75a3e880e

Comment: What probabilities did you use? Are the probabilities themselves random? Does the contestant know them?

Comment: The probabilities are random themselves. The contestant does not know the probabilities.

Comment: According to what distribution are the probabilities chosen?

Comment: They are randomly chosen. There is no distribution to the probabilities. (Used python's random number generator).

Comment: you can spare us the details of the programming (maybe), but not the details of the game.

Comment: There is always a distribution (maybe uniform? what function did you use?)... you may just want to post the code or at least some pseudo code or a detailed description of how the game goes. Otherwise it's just going to be a guessing game.

Comment: If the probabilities are randomly chosen, then Python generates them according to some probability distribution.

Comment: At the very least, the probabilities have to be positive and add to $1$ -- they can't just be random numbers...

Comment: Yes the probabilities do add to 1.

Comment: Are you assuming there is exactly one prize or are you allowing there to be two prizes?

Comment: Only one prize. Everything is same as original Monty Hall Problem except the probabilities of the car being behind the doors.

Comment: Have you checked that when you change the p's back to $1/3$ that you get the correct result of $2/3$?

Comment: No I have not. I will check that right now.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen I do get 1/3 and 2/3 probabilities when $p_1 = p_2 = p_3$

Comment: I think this is an artefact of the way you construct the probabilities $(p_1,p_2,p_3)$. In particular, notice that $\Pr(p_1 \ge 1/2) = 1/2$, so it seems that the car is behind door $1$ more often than not.

Comment: Given that it appears you made some rather unusual choices in how to model your randomness, I think you really should show us the full code you used.

Comment: Here it is: https://www.pastiebin.com/5a4d75a3e880e.

Comment: Do you by chance assume they always initially stand behind door one (cause that would explain it)?

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen the code suggests that they do always start with door one.

Comment: Yes, I do. I assume this but reason this is valid because doors 1, 2, 3 are just labels. In other words door 1 can become door 2 if I switch their spots. Since the probabilities are random I figured it would not matter.

Comment: @MadhavNakar: They are not just labels, since you assign probabilities to each of them in different ways!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your setup, the probability the prize is behind door $a$ is $E(p_1) = \frac{1}{2}$ and you also assume they start in front of door $a,$ so there is indeed a $1/2$ probability of getting the prize regardless if you switch or not.

Comment: I updated the code and now I am completely baffled yet fascinated. Running the code several times gives different probabilities for switching and not switching each time (remember running the code once plays the game a million times). However, each time the probabilities of switching vs never switching yields results close to $\frac{1}{4}, \frac{1}{2}$ or $\frac{3}{4}$. But the probabilities of switching and never switching do not always add to 1.

Comment: @MadhavNakar Perhaps you're mistakenly not resetting the randomization in the inner loop? This is what I would expect if you generated probabilities as above, randomly picked a starting choice (door a b or c) then played this choice a million times and switched. Then pick a new starting choice and play it a million times while not switching. This would yield a random mix of $1/2$ 's and $3/4$'s for switching and a random mix of $1/2$'s and $1/4$'s for not switching.

Comment: I checked the code, but the function that I included in the question is called inside the loop. So, that function is called a million times twice.

Comment: @MadhavNakar I wasn't saying the function assigning the $p$'s isn't called in the inner loop... I was saying the function that randomizes which door is chosen first maybe isn't (which I presumed was the modification you made). I guess I should have asked this first: what update did you make to the code?

Comment: Now I understand what you mean. I have made the mistake which you have described. By the way, can this be solved mathematically instead of experimentation? My first guess is that since the probabilities are random, then it does not matter whether you switch or not because you do not know the probabilities.

Comment: Interestingly now I seem to be getting results like I would if $p_1 = p_2 = p_3 = \frac{1}{3}$. Never switching is around $0.333$ and switching is around $0.666$.

Comment: Yes. The probability that you win when you stay put is exactly the probability that you start out in front of the door with the prize, and the probability you win by switching is one minus that. So the optimal strategy depends on your *belief* about the probability the prize is behind each door. If you have no good reason to suspect it is behind one door rather than the other, then you should switch. And you expect a probability of $2/3$ for doing this. (Which is why you're seeing it revert to the usual when you randomize).

Comment: Now, it might be the case that you play this game many times and take careful statistics and discover that the programmer has arranged it so that there is a $1/2,$ $1/4,$ $1/4$ probability of being behind $A, B,C$ in which case you update your beliefs and the optimal strategy is to pick door $B$ or $C$ and switch for a $3/4$ probability of winning.

Comment: Put another way, assuming there is some process assigning the prize to the doors that doesn't change statistically in time, the optimal strategy is unknown and is a function of $E(p_1)$ and $E(p_2)$ (and hopefully you've gleaned by now from our answers that your extra source of randomness for the $p$'s really doesn't really add any more randomness than choosing $p_1$ and $p_2$ to be some constants). For instance if one has a near zero probability, you should pick that one and switch and if one has a near-one probability you should pick that one and stay.

Comment: So you'd need to make some best guess for what $p_1$ and $p_2$ are and thus what the optimal strategy is. If you have seen the game played a bunch you may decide that recoding and analyzing the data is a good way of informing your guess. This is statistical inference.

Comment: Very interesting. So if Monty changes probabilities for each door to have the car for every contestant, the best/optimal strategy is just to guess since we cannot deduce anything about our probability based on what others had. But if Monty doesn't change then clearly you can use previous data.

Comment: Yes but I'll emphasize that your initial game here 'changed the probabilities' in a certain sense and yet it was exploitable. Since $p_1=p_2=1/3$ offers the worst optimal response, Monty's best strategy playing repeatedly against an arbitrarily smart opponent is to expose no statistical information about future probabilities. One simple way is to choose the door independently and uniformly at random by some mechanism. A similar equilibrium exists in the game 'rock, paper, scissors' (the less talented guesser can just play randomly and avoid being exploited.)

Answer (score 5):

This is just an artifact of the way you randomly generated $p_1$, $p_2$, and $p_3$.  Note that randomly generating these three probabilities and then using them to pick the winning door is equivalent to just using the average randomly generated value of each of them as your probabilities to pick the winning door.  You have chosen $p_1$ uniformly between $0$ and $1$, so its average value is $1/2$.  You then chose $p_2$ uniformly between $0$ and $1-p_1$.  Since this bound is linear in $p_1$ and the average value of $p_1$ is $1/2$, the average value of $p_2$ is $1/4$.  Finally, the average value of $p_3$ is $1-1/2-1/4=1/4$.

So what you have done is completely equivalent to running the game with $p_1=1/2$, $p_2=1/4$, and $p_3=1/4$.  Since you collected your data based on the assumption that the player always chooses door 1 first, that means they have a $1/2$ chance of being correct initially, and therefore there is a $1/2$ chance that they should not switch.

Comment: That was quick. +1

Comment: I updated the code and now I am completely baffled yet fascinated. Running the code several times gives different probabilities for switching and not switching each time (remember running the code once plays the game a million times). However, each time the probabilities of switching vs never switching yields results close to $\frac{1}{4}, \frac{1}{2}$ or $\frac{3}{4}$. But the probabilities of switching and never switching do not always add to 1.